# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I've configured maven-surefire-plugin in pom.xml like:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.18.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
      <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But when I hit `mvn install`, it results into following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project MavenTest: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/testng/annotations/Test : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.tryLoadClass(ReflectionUtils.java:229)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.<clinit>(TestNGExecutor.java:59)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:84)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:90)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

I searched over internet but could not find anything helpful. Could you someone please help me on this?

Comment: There's a similar issue already created: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27439564/mvn-test-fails-because-of-surefire-jdk-version

Answer (score 1):

The line:

> [ERROR] java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/testng/annotations/Test : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Shows that there is a miss-match of java versions.
For example, you are trying to run the test process with a java version older than the one used to compile the test classes.

You should align all steps to use the same java version.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you used IDEA and Maven, try toggle "Skip Tests" Mode