# Unsupported java class version 52

Tags: java, classloader, unsupported-class-version

I have found quite some related questions, but not one that could solve my problem.
I have some Java source code in my eclipse project, I get a 
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/hibernate/HibernateException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`
When running my class, even though its a Hibernate exception, the inner exception comes from the ClassLoader after invoking a default constructor.
It is clear to me that apparently I am running in `JRE7` a class compiled with java8 compiler, however, I can't see that in my project configuration, here's the compiler (1.7):
[image: Compiler:]

And here's the JRE:
[image]

Also from *window > preference > Java > compiler*, I see that is compiled in java 7
[image]

After cleaning the project several times, so to make sure no old classes are there, and resolving dependencies in maven, I still get this.
Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @soorapadman Not a possible duplicate, related, but not the same, the other one is running from command line compiling source code from a notepad file

Comment: to resolve your issue could you use same java version ?

Comment: check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24790834/cant-fix-unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0-even-after-fixing-compatibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably in your classpath there are some libs compiled with JDK8.

Comment: someone had updated pom.xml on remote repo to download hibernate core 5.2.2 which needs java 8, grazie mauretto

Answer (score 0):

Probably the class compiled with java 8 is not in your code, but in a library imported in your code.

Check the version of each library imported in your project to see if one of them needs java 8 as a requirement.